# cross compile for aosp

Tags: android, cross-compiling, android-source

Is there a proven method to cross compile native code for android aosp?  I was able to successfully compile a jni shared library on aosp and link the prebuilt.  Unfortunately, the shared library contents show the native methods as undefined:

```
/library/libtest_jni.so:     file format elf32-little
DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
00000000      D  *UND*  00000000 _ZN8namespaceA17namespaceB17Test6createEv
```

Steps:

1. compiled the prebuilts with the android ndk toolchain for both 32 and 64 arm.
2. created Android.mk:

   ```
   LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

   include $(CLEAR_VARS)
   LOCAL_MODULE := libtest_jni
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Test.cpp
   LOCAL_LDLIBS_64 := $(LOCAL_PATH)/libtest64.so
   LOCAL_LDLIBS_32 := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../libtest32.so
   include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
   ```

Comment: Was there a specific reason for compiling `libtest_jni.so` in AOSP build system, without using Android NDK toolchain? If we can compile the JNI shared library using NDK, link `libtest` library as a static libraries (`.a`) to the `libtest_jni` target, I think we can include the JNI shared library as a pre-built to the AOSP build.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something compiled with NDK tool-chain will work under AOSP but due to security reason NDK and AOSP have different STL libraries which are not compatible. For example, when I tried to use NDK compiled Boost libraries like prebuilts under AOSP I got linker errors due to mismatches in STL namespaces (std::__1 vs std::__ndk1).

For cross-compiling it is needed to support both build systems by creating two build scripts: CMakeLists.txt for NDK and Android.bp for AOSP.

Here is example of cross-complied library: https://github.com/nkh-lab/logger